# openerp and php xmlrpc is not working on shared hosting but working on localhost

Tags: php, odoo, xml-rpc

I have ipage host server when i tried to upload my php code on my server, it is not establishing connection with openerp but when i tried it on localhost it is working fine 
and generating lead. I want it working on my website on live shared server (Ipage).
This is my Openerp-server Configuration file
My openerp server is hosted on local server and i am connecting it through static IP address

```
 [options]
 ; This is the password that allows database operations: 
 ; admin_passwd = XXXXXX
 db_host = False
 db_port = False
 db_user = openerp 
 xmlrpc =  True
 xmlrpc_port = 8069
 xml_netrpc = 8071
 db_password = False
 logfile = /var/log/openerp/openerp-server.log
```

This is my crmlead.php file

```
<?php

include("xmlrpc.inc");      

class Contact
{
private $subject = '', $to = '';

function __construct($to, $sub)
{
    $this->to = $to;
    $this->subject = $sub;
}


function xmlCallTo($usr, $password, $database, $server, $post)
{
    $user = $usr;
    $pass = $password;
    $db = $database;
    $server_url = $server; //'http://localhost:8069/xmlrpc/'

    $client = new xmlrpc_client($server_url.'common');

    $msg = new xmlrpcmsg('login');
    $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($db, "string"));
    $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($user, "string"));
    $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($pass, "string"));


    $res =  &$client->send($msg);

    if(!$res->faultCode()){

        $val = $res->value();   
        $id = $val->scalarval();

        if (empty($id)){

            echo "Connection error = ";
            exit;
        }
        else
        {
            $client2 = new xmlrpc_client($server_url.'object');
            $key = array(new xmlrpcval(array(new xmlrpcval("code", "string"), new xmlrpcval("=", "string"), new xmlrpcval($post['country'], "string")),"array"),);
            $msg = new xmlrpcmsg('execute');
            $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($db, "string"));
            $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($id, "int"));
            $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($pass, "string"));
            $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval("res.country","string"));
            $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval("search", "string"));
            $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($key, "array"));
            $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval(0, "int"));
            $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval(1, "int"));

            $res = &$client2->send($msg);

            $val = $res->value()->scalarval();

            $countryId = $val[0]->scalarval();

            $val = array ("name" => new xmlrpcval($post['company'],"string"),
                          "email_from" => new xmlrpcval($post['email'], "string"),
                          "phone" => new xmlrpcval($post['phone'], "string"),
                          "partner_name" => new xmlrpcval($post['name'], "string"),
                          "function" => new xmlrpcval($post["jobtitle"], "string"),
                          "zip" => new xmlrpcval($post['zip'], "string"),
                          "stage_id" => new xmlrpcval(2, "int"),
                          "city" => new xmlrpcval($post['city'], "string"),
                          "country_id" => new xmlrpcval($countryId, "int"),
                          "state" => new xmlrpcval("draft", "string"),
                          "user_id" => new xmlrpcval(false, "boolean"),
                          "description" => new xmlrpcval("No.of Employees: ".$post['employees']."\nState: ".$post['state']."\nIndustry: ".$post['industry']."\nAbout: ".$post['about'], "string")
                        );

            $msg = new xmlrpcmsg('execute');
            $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($db, "string"));
            $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($id, "int"));
            $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($pass, "string"));
            $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval("crm.lead", "string"));
            $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval("create", "string"));
            $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($val, "struct"));


            $res2 = &$client2->send($msg);

            if(!$res2->faultCode())
            {
                $readVal = $res2->value()->scalarval();

                if (!empty($readVal))
                {
                    $val = array ( "description" => new xmlrpcval("About: ".$post['about']),
                            "model_id" => new xmlrpcval(276, "int"),
                            "res_id" => new xmlrpcval($readVal,"int"),
                            "email_from" => new xmlrpcval($post['email'], "string"),
                            "email_to" => new xmlrpcval("sales@openerp.com", "string")
                            );


                    $msg = new xmlrpcmsg('execute');
                    $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($db, "string"));
                    $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($id, "int"));
                    $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($pass, "string"));
                    $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval("crm.case.history", "string"));
                    $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval("create", "string"));
                    $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($val, "struct"));

                    $res2 = &$client2->send($msg);

                    //echo "<br />Successfully created lead";
                    echo "<br /><h3>Thank You for your interest in openerp, we'll respond to your request shortly.</h3><br />";
                    if(strstr($post["about"],"Book")) {
                        echo '<script>window.location="http://www.openerp.com/index.php?option=com_content&amp;id=54"</script>';
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "<br />Lead is not created";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<br />Problem in message sending for create lead";
            }
        }           
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<br />Connection not established";
    }
}
 }

if(isset($_POST['country']) && $_POST['country'] != '') {
    $arrData = array();
    $arrData = array_merge($arrData, (array)$_POST);

    $cnt = new Contact('sales5@openerp.com', 'Country: '.$arrData['country']. ' About: ' .$arrData['about']);

    /* This function use for sending mail on perticular mail account */
    /*$cnt->mailTo($arrData); */

    /* This function use ceating lead in crm of opener erp database */
    //Change to fit your configuration
    $cnt->xmlCallTo('admin', 'a', 'db_1', 'http://localhost:8069/xmlrpc/', $arrData);
}
else {
    echo 'please fill the form at <a href="form.php">form.php</a>';
}

exit;
```

?>

this is my countrylist.php

```
<?php
include("xmlrpc.inc");

//Change to fit your configuration
$user = "admin";
$password = "a";
$db = "db_1";
$serverUri = "http://localhost:8069/xmlrpc/";


$client = new xmlrpc_client($serverUri.'common');

$msg = new xmlrpcmsg('login');
$msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($db, "string"));
$msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($user, "string"));
$msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($password, "string"));


$res =  &$client->send($msg);

if(!$res->faultCode()){

    $id = $res->value()->scalarval();   

    $client = new xmlrpc_client($serverUri.'object');

    $key = array(new xmlrpcval(array(new xmlrpcval("id", "string"),
                new xmlrpcval(">", "string"),
                new xmlrpcval(0, "int")),"array"),);



    $msg = new xmlrpcmsg('execute');
    $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($db, "string"));
    $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($id, "int"));
    $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($password, "string"));
    $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval("res.country","string"));
    $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval("search", "string"));      
    $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($key, "array"));
    $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval(0, "int"));
    $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval(0, "int"));
    $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval("id ASC", "string"));

    $res = &$client->send($msg);

    if(!$res->faultCode())
    {
        $val = $res->value()->scalarval();

        $ides = array();

        for ($i=0 ; $i<count($val); $i++)
        {
            array_push($ides, new xmlrpcval($val[$i]->scalarval(), "int"));
        }

        $client = new xmlrpc_client($serverUri.'object');

        $fields = array(new xmlrpcval("code", "string"), new xmlrpcval("name", "string"));

        $msg = new xmlrpcmsg('execute');
        $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($db, "string"));
        $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($id, "int"));
        $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($password, "string"));
        $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval("res.country","string"));
        $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval("read", "string"));
        $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($ides, "array"));
        $msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($fields, "array"));

        $res = &$client->send($msg);

        if (!$res->faultCode())
        {
            $val = $res->value()->scalarval();

            $select ='<select class="inputbox required"  name="country" id="country" >                                  
                        <option value="" selected="selected"> -- Select an Option --     </option>';

            for ($i=0; $i<count($val);$i++)
            {
                $field = $val[$i]->scalarval();
                $select .= '<option value="'.$field['code']->scalarval().'">'.$field['name']->scalarval().'</option>';
              }

            $select .= '</select>';

            echo $select;
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Country not getting";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Country list id empty";
    }       
}
else
{
    echo "connection not establish";
}


?>
```

and finaly this is my form.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Contact form</title>
</head>
<body>
<h4>Contact Form</h4>
<form method="post" action="crmlead.php">
    <label for="firstname">Firstname</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" value="" id="firstname" class="required text" title="Please, fill in your firstname" data-required="true"><br />
    <label for="company">Company</label>
        <input type="text" name="company" value="" id="company" class="required text" title="Please, fill in your company name" data-required="true"><br />
    <label for="jobtitle">Jobtitle</label>
        <input type="text" name="jobtitle" value="" id="jobtitle" class="required text" title="Please, fill in your job title" data-required="true"><br />
    <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" value="" id="email" class="required email text" title="Please, enter a valid email address" data-required="true"><br />
    <label for="phone">Phone</label>
        <input type="text" name="phone" value="" id="phone" class="required phone text" title="Please use international format (eg: +32...)" data-required="true">

    <label for="city">City</label>
        <input type="text" name="city" value="" id="city" class="required text" title="Please, fill in your city" data-required="true"><br />
    <label for="zip">Zipcode</label>
        <td><input type="text" name="zip" value="" id="zip" class="required text" title="Please, fill in your zipcode" data-required="true"><br />
    <label for="state">State</label><input type="text" name="state" value="" id="state" class="text" title="Please, fill in your state"> <br />
    <label> Country : <?php include('countrylist.php'); ?></label> <br />
    <label for="employees">No.of employees</label>

            <select class="required" name="employees" title="Please, select the No. of employees" data-required="true">
                <option value=""> -- select an option -- </option>
                <option value="1-5">1-5</option>
                <option value="5-10">5-10</option>
                <option value="10-20">10-20</option>

                <option value="20-100">20-100</option>
                <option value="100-500">100-500</option>
                <option value="500+">500+</option>
            </select><br />

          <label for="industry">Industry expertise</label>
            <select class="required select" name="industry" title="Please, select an industry" data-required="true">
                <option value=""> -- select an option -- </option>
                <option value="auction">Auction Houses</option>
                <option value="bank">Bank</option>
                <option value="distribution">Distribution</option>
                <option value="education">Education</option>

                <option value="entertainment">Entertainment</option>
                <option value="erp_integrator">ERP Integrator</option>
                <option value="food_industries">Food industries</option>
                <option value="hotels_restaurants">Hotels &amp; restaurants</option>
                <option value="insurance">Insurance</option>
                <option value="manufacturing">Manufacturing</option>
                <option value="non_profit">Non-Profit</option>
                <option value="public">Public</option>

                <option value="services">Services</option>
                <option value="telecommunication">Telecommunication</option>
                <option value="others">Others</option>
            </select><br />
    <p>
        <label> About : <textarea name="about"></textarea></textarea></label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Send"/> <input type="reset" />
    </p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it's not possible post ur code here

Comment: Can you post the configuration file of you openerp-server ?

Comment: I have update my openerp-server file on the above

Comment: We need more information. What does you php script look like? Which kind of connector do you use exactly? Are there any error messages in your logfiles? Where is the openerp hosted?

Comment: i have update my question with code

Comment: in countrylist.php serveruri is defined as localhost did u host both php and openerp in same server ?

Comment: no i am not hosting on same server on my shared server i have given the url of my openerp-server so it's not localhost

Comment: but in upper php code it's localhost so you can imaging it's my server url (or ignor it )